# addEdge for Graph is return null pointer?

Tags: java, graph, nullpointerexception, vertex, adjacency-list

So I am trying to understand hashmaps and graphs, when I run my code, I always get a null pointer exception. on line 25 with "adjVertices.get(v1).add(v2);" and I am sure the next line would throw it too if it would get to it. what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Graph {

    private Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> adjVertices;

    Graph() {
        this.adjVertices = new HashMap<Vertex, List<Vertex>>();
    }

    class Vertex {
        String label;
        Vertex(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }
    }

    void addVertex(String label) {
        adjVertices.putIfAbsent(new Vertex(label), new ArrayList<>());
    }

    void addEdge(String label1, String label2) {
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex(label1);
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex(label2);
        adjVertices.get(v1).add(v2);
        adjVertices.get(v2).add(v1);
    }

}
```

Here is what my main looks like:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Create a graph given in the above diagram
        Graph g = new Graph();
        g.addVertex("CS2010");
        g.addVertex("CS2370");
        g.addVertex("CS2381");
        g.addVertex("CS3221");
        g.addVertex("CS3600");
        g.addEdge("CS2010", "CS2370");
        g.addEdge("CS2370", "CS2381");
        g.addEdge("CS2370", "CS3600");
        g.addEdge("CS2381", "CS3221");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I always get a null pointer exception. on line 25 with
>   "adjVertices.get(v1).add(v2) ... what am I missing?

If `adjVertices.get(v1)` returns `null`, the expression, `adjVertices.get(v1).add(v2)` will throw `NullPointerException` because `.add(v2)` will be called on a `null` reference. Do it as follows:

```
void addEdge(String label1, String label2) {
    Vertex v1 = new Vertex(label1);
    Vertex v2 = new Vertex(label2);
    if (adjVertices.get(v1) != null) {
        adjVertices.get(v1).add(v2);
    }
    if (adjVertices.get(v2) != null) {
        adjVertices.get(v2).add(v1);
    }
}
```

Another problem in your code is that you haven't implemented `hashCode` and `equals` in `Vertex`. Make sure to implement `hashCode` and `equals` in the class whenever you are going to add the instances of this class into a `HashMap`. Given below is the complete code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

class Vertex {
    String label;

    Vertex(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(label);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return label.equals(((Vertex) obj).label);
    }
}

class Graph {

    public Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> adjVertices;

    Graph() {
        this.adjVertices = new HashMap<Vertex, List<Vertex>>();
    }

    void addVertex(String label) {
        adjVertices.putIfAbsent(new Vertex(label), new ArrayList<>());
    }

    void addEdge(String label1, String label2) {
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex(label1);
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex(label2);
        if (adjVertices.get(v1) != null) {
            adjVertices.get(v1).add(v2);
        }
        if (adjVertices.get(v2) != null) {
            adjVertices.get(v2).add(v1);
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Create a graph given in the above diagram
        Graph g = new Graph();
        g.addVertex("CS2010");
        g.addVertex("CS2370");
        g.addVertex("CS2381");
        g.addVertex("CS3221");
        g.addVertex("CS3600");
        g.addEdge("CS2010", "CS2370");
        g.addEdge("CS2370", "CS2381");
        g.addEdge("CS2370", "CS3600");
        g.addEdge("CS2381", "CS3221");
        System.out.println(g.adjVertices);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Vertex@76fdc54d=[Vertex@76fdd14a], Vertex@76fe414e=[Vertex@76fdd16a], Vertex@76fdd14a=[Vertex@76fdc54d, Vertex@76fdd16a, Vertex@76fe5013], Vertex@76fdd16a=[Vertex@76fdd14a, Vertex@76fe414e], Vertex@76fe5013=[Vertex@76fdd14a]}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. I tried our your code and my graph won't populate. I think they are always coming up null, and I have no idea why

Comment: You are most welcome. I had given an example only for one case and I thought you would apply it for both the cases. You need to check `null` in both the cases i.e. when you add `v1` to `v2` or when you add `v2` to `v1`.  I've updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if you face any further issue.

Comment: @user12763568 - Check the update again. I've posted some important points. I've also posted the working code.  Let me know if you face any further issue.